# what version can I use for nightly build in electron app?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am build `electron app` and need to publish nightly build. I want to give a special version for nightly bulid which is `dd-mm-yyyy` but it doesn't work because `electron` only supports Semantic version. What version can I use for nightly build which doesn't break Semantic version rules?